# Angular 12 - have a standard routerLink, but it reloads always the page and the null value not working (href setted to current page)

Tags: angular12, routerlink

On an angular 12 application, I use a quite ordinary a with a routerLink.

First, I don't know why, it always refreshes my page... it relocates the whole page with each click.

Also, when I set the routerLink to "null", my link is still active. My href is set with the current page.

I've done the same thing in several applications and I don't get this behavior.

Anyone have any idea why it behaves like this?

Here is my html code for the link :

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let el of sidebarMenu">
    <a class="sidebar-menu-item" [routerLink]="el.route">
        <mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-round">{{ el.icon }}</mat-icon>
        <span>{{ el.label }}</span>
    </a>
</ng-container>
```

If I write "null", my link remains active on the current page.

Thanking you.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the code works if it's not dynamically generated...

The problem is fixed without the loop on the elements.